# How can I set rigid body active to an object at certain keyframe?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

here's the issue:

I achieved to create several objects on different layers over z axis and insert objects per layer at desired keyframe. So I can simulate realistic construction.

The problem now is if there is any possibility to activate rigid body physics instead of animated interaction at certain keyframe. Since is mandatory to let objects from different layers free fall they interact in some situations because they are close enough to touch each other.

Even though both dynamic and animated options are disable until target layer needs to interact with gravity.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the *Rigid Body* object to fall with gravity, you have to keep *Dynamic* enabled.

Go to the last frame where the *Rigid Body* object should be animated. Right-click on the *Animated* checkbox and choose *Insert Keyframe* (or click the dot on the right to set the keyframe).

Go to the next frame, disable *Animated*, right-click again to set a keyframe or click the dot symbol.

EDIT: As you wrote in the comments, you want to have a *Rigid Body* object not interacting with other *Rigid Bodies* until it is set to *Dynamic*. There is a setting which might help - it's not connected to the *Dynamic* setting so you have to keyframe it separately.

In the *Rigid Body Settings* further below you will find *Collections* (quite vague name, but the tooltip says "Collision Collections"). It looks like the *Layers* from older Blender versions. There you can select for each object to which "Collection" it belongs by clicking with <kbd>LMB</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> for multiple collections.

This whole configuration table can actually be keyframed, too. So, by default all *Rigid Bodies* are in the top left collection. If you now have one *Rigid Body* that should not interact with them until e.g. frame 50, then set it on the second slot. Go to frame 49, hit <kbd>I</kbd> while hovering your mouse over the table to add a keyframe. Then go to frame 50, select the first slot and hit <kbd>I</kbd> again. Now the object is in the same collection as the other *Rigid Bodies* and interacts with them.

[image: rigid body collections]

Comment: Thanks buddy for answering, maybe thats my fault that i didnt mean correctly. I already achieve this. The thing is if there is any posibility to avoid physics interaction until object is set dynamic. For instance, two layers of objects at created through scrpiting, but sometimes since they are rotated randomly, they can be in touch with each other and fly without control. Do you know if that is possible?

Comment: @SergioMuñozPalao Oh, now I understand. I've edited my answer to give that as additional information. Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks so much, really! this solution solved my problem, i will clean up my script so it works perfectly. :)